What shape is the waterfall start line on a track?
The most common shape of a 400m outdoor running track is called a stadium in mathematics and consists of a rectangle capped off by semicircular ends.  The length of the straight and the radius of the bend differ for different tracks, but for the purposes of this question, one may assume the radius of the semicircle is a unit $1$.
A track has many different markings on it.  One of the curved markings is sometimes called a "waterfall start".  On this 400 metre standard track marking plan [0.8 MB, single-page PDF], the marking I'm referencing shares a point with the finish line and is labeled as the start for "2000m, 4 x 800m, Distance Medley Relay, 4 x 1500m, 10,000m" and symmetrically for "1000m, 3000m, 5000m".  [Similar, but different, markings define the start of 1500m, 2000m, 1 mile, and 3000m steeplechase.  There are also "group start" / "double waterfall" markings in the outer lanes.]  To match the orientation of this PDF, I will place the start of the inner lane at $(0,-1)$ in the plane for the diagrams below, though presumably it's mathematically more standard to use $(1,0)$.
This curve can be obtained by wrapping a string tightly around the semicircle and then unwrapping it while still holding it taut, marking the end as one goes.  This curve looks like so on an actual track [inside rail in orange, curve in blue]:

There is a straightforward interpretation of extending the curve further, at least until the string unwraps entirely off the semicircle [bend still in orange, curve still in blue]:

For example, the point at the upper-right of this diagram $(\pi, 1)$ corresponds to where you should start so that if you run directly left you would continue directly onto the back straight.  The lowest point on the diagram $(1,-\pi/2)$ corresponds to where you should start so that if you run directly up you would join the bend exactly halfway.
Going further than this no longer has a direct interpretation on the track because the length of the straightaway begins to matter, but mathematically speaking one could just extend the curve even further to form a spiral.  I plot it here with a more mathematically-natural beginning at $(1,0)$: [One can also consider unwrapping a "negative" amount of string, but this just produces a reflection!]

Does this spiral have a name?  Has it been studied?  What is an equation defining the curve?  Are any properties of the curve known, for example its length (over some portion)?
